# How can we derive the formula for sum of odd numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

We know that $\sum^n_{k=1}(2k-1)=n^2$. Can it be shown using AP?

Comment: What is AP? Arithmetic progression?

Comment: Yes. Can it be shown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you just have to put the values.

$$\text{Sum = S}_n = \frac{n(2a+(n-1)d)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{n(2+(n-1)2)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{2n(n-1+1)}{2}={n^2}$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\def\r{\color{red}{\bullet}}\def\b{\color{blue}{\bullet}}
  \matrix{\r&\b&\r&\b&\r&\b\cr \b&\b&\r&\b&\r&\b\cr \r&\r&\r&\b&\r&\b\cr
          \b&\b&\b&\b&\r&\b\cr \r&\r&\r&\r&\r&\b\cr \b&\b&\b&\b&\b&\b\cr}$$

Comment: Is this Arithmetic Progression?

Comment: The sides grow by one, the same colour layers (odd numbers) by 2. So it is used at least.

Answer (score 2):

$S_n = \frac{a_1 + a_n}{2} * n$
$a_1 = 1, a_n = 2n - 1 \Rightarrow S_n = \frac{2n}{2} * n = n^2$

Answer (score 1):

**1st Method**

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2k-1\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n2k-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n1=2\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk-n=\left(2 \cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-n=n^2$

**2nd Method**

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2k-1\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}k-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k=\dfrac{2n(2n-1)}{2}-n(n-1)=n(2n-1-n+1)=n^2$

**3rd Method**

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2k-1\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left((k+1)^2-k^2\right)=n^2$

Comment: @StevenGregory: Isn't it essentially similar to Timbuc's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Another method, similar to the one little Gauss probably used for the sum of all consecutive integers between $\;1\;$ and $\;n\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}\text{(ascending)}\;\;&S=&1&+&3&+&\ldots&+&(2n-3)&+&(2n-1)\\
\text{(descending)}\;\;&S=&(2n-1)&+&(2n-3)&+&\ldots&+&3&+&1\end{align*}$$

Now sum up summandwise both lines above:

$$2S=\overbrace{2n+2n+\ldots+2n}^{n\;\text{ times}}=2n^2$$

and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use induction:

Base case:
$$1=1^2$$

Step:
$$1+3+...+2n-1=n^2 ⇒ 1+3+...+2n-1+2n+1=n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$$